# Orders of sections of line bundles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth curve of genus $g$, let $L$ be a line bundle on $C$ and let $V\subseteq H^0(X,L)$ be a linear subspace of dimension $r$. Fix $p\in C$. Prove that $$\{\text{ord}_p\sigma\}_{\sigma\in V\setminus\{0\}}$$ is a set of exactly $r$ nonnegative integers.

I managed to prove through a brute-force computation that for $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $L=\mathcal{O}(d)$ a generic choice of a basis of $V$ yields $r$ distinct orders.

Comment: Let $0\neq\sigma\in V$ be chosen with the least order, say $m$. Show that $W\subset V$ where $W$ consists of all $\tau\in V$ with $\mathrm{ord}_p\tau>m$ is a complementary subspace to the one dimensional subspace generated by $\sigma$ and now induction on $r$ finishes the proof.

Comment: I guess it's implicit when you mention $g$ but you probably want to say that $C$ is projective, right? You don't want too many global functions floating around.